# Powershell: Getting users for whom retention policy has been enabled based on content type

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, skype-for-business

Is there a way to get the list of users for which retention policy has been enabled based on the content type i.e: Email, Skype for Business, Onedrive and et al.?  There are these commands to see the policy and rule but I could not find anyway to get the content and the list of users for which retention policy has been enabled.

[Get-RetentionComplianceRule](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt691476(v=exchg.160).aspx)

[Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/mt691471(v=exchg.160).aspx)

[image]

Basically, I want a way to retrieve the users for Skype for Business in enclosed on red section in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`Get-RetentionCompliancePolicy -identity "SfB_Retention" -distributiondetail | Select-Object SkypeLocation`

Comment: is this documented somewhere?